# SimpleMessageListenerContainer separate queue for each listener (java configuration)

Tags: spring-amqp

I am trying to convert following xml configuration to java configuration. This configuration mentions that listener1 will retrieve message from queue1 and listener2 from queue2

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    <rabbit:listener ref="listener1" queues="queue1" />
    <rabbit:listener ref="listener2" queues="queue2" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

with java configuration, I have done following:

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
container.setQueues(queue1(), queue2());
container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter1());
container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter2());
```

With this configuration, how to configure listener1 to retrieve message from queue1 and listener2 to retrieve message from queue2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XML configuration parser creates a new `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` for each `<rabbit:listener />` element.

A container can only have one listener; the XML is just a convenient way to wire up multiple containers with common properties (from the `<rabbit:listener-container/>` element).